# Ошибка при сборе статики

Tags: python, django, static

Загружаю проект на продакшн в первый раз. 
При сборе статики выдает ошибку:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
> You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Вот часть файла **settings.py**:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent (эта строка в начале файла)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'static',)
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static' - меняла на STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Пробовала менять на:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'static',)
```

Выдает другую ошибку:

> ERRORS:?: (staticfiles.E002) 
> The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Потом изменяла на это:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = []
```

Ошибка та же.

Comment: А `debug` поменяла на `False` ?)))

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS — это каталоги, **откуда** берутся файлы. STATIC_ROOT — это каталог, **куда** кладутся файлы при запуске collectstatic. Каталоги «откуда» и «куда» не могут быть одним и тем же каталогом

Comment: При загрузке на продакшен нужно выполнить команду collectstatic — она скопирует все файлы из каталогов приложений и из STATICFILES_DIRS и каталог STATIC_ROOT, а потом этот STATIC_ROOT нужно подключить к продакшеновому веб-серверу для раздачи файлов из него. А вот эти ваши манипуляции с `if DEBUG` это чушь непонятная какая-то